# IIS and asp mvc : how enable access to folder in filesystem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

in asp mvc i have publish a website in this folder:

```
C:\IISWorkspace\MyWebSite
```

Now inside the folder C:\TestImages i want that the user is able to create some subfolders and put some images.

For example i have created this folder and put an image:

```
C:\TestImages\Test1\image1.png
```

Now, in my razor view i have put this code

```
<img src="C:\TestImages\Test1\image1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

but nothing is showed.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Clasic ASP.

Comment: Or not even with `MVC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser can't access your file system due to security concerns.You will have to host your images in IIS

Create a virtual directory for you images folder C:\TestImages.

let's say, your virtual directory name is MyImages(mapped with C:\TestImages) under default website, then you can give path as localhost\MyImages\Test1\image1.png